# Make excel stdev function take specific text as a certain number

Tags: excel, average

I am trying to make excel's standard deviation function to consider a specific text found in the range as a number provided in another cell. Is there any way to do this? If possible, I would not want to use another column of cells as an intermediate step.

I have a series of measurements, however some values are below the detection limit. Instead of calculating the stdev with these values , I want to type 'LDL' (lower detection limit) into these cells. The stdev function should then, every time it encounters 'LDL', fetch the detection limit (LOD) from another cell.
Example:

> .... LOD= ...2 ....
>   .... .... .... ....
>   .... ...5 .... ....
>   .... ...8 .... ....
>   .... LDL. .... ....
>   .... ...7 .... ....
>   .... ---- .... ....
>   STD. =STDEV(B3:B6 but consider B5 as C1)

Thanks in advance for all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an **array formula****:

=STDEV(0+SUBSTITUTE(B3:B6,"LDL",C1))

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: That indeed works. Although one has to separate SUBSTITUTE's arguments by a semicolon (edited in your answer). I can even drag the formula to other cells to calculate more SDs in the same way, so perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Could you maybe explain the '0+'?

Comment: SUBSTITUTE returns a text string. Any suitable numerical operation which also leaves the value unchanged will convert any text strings which represent numbers to actual numbers. Addition of zero is one such operation. Multiplication by one would be another. Double-negation (--) yet another.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=(SUM(B3:B6)+COUNTIF(B3:B6,"LDL")*B1)/COUNTA(B3:B6)
```

Comment: For the average, that works perfectly fine. Initially, I asked for the average, but that was my mistake, I meant the standard deviation. Sry, if you answered to the pre-edited post. I need the average as well though, so thank you anyway.